# What are three dots in this DFA?

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, automata, nfa, automata-theory

I need to understand this DFA? I have failed to understand it, especially three dots in the diagram. I am getting a vague idea of why is a transition pointing to where it is pointing. But I am still very confused. So it will be great if somebody can tell **what these dots mean**:

**1. When they appear on the name of a transition, like 1?
 2. When they appear between two states which are not connected?**

[image]

Comment: its simply mean there are many others instead of only this transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simply mean there are many others instead of only this transition.you can see after `q001 , q101` comes.and horizontal dots shows `q00 , q01, q10 , q11` also connects with them which are not written here.